# How to force a drive to mount at startup in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount

In Ubuntu I have an external USB drive that gets automounted when accessed through Nautilus. The problem is that if I first open up a terminal and try to access the files, they're not there. I have to first access the drive through Nautilus. After that a folder is created in the /mount directory and I can access the files in the terminal.

How can I get access to the drive in the terminal without first having to access it like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Mattias suggested (+1) the `/etc/fstab` is the place to add correct entry.

But, you may want to identify the block device in different way. For example if you have another pendrive/disk/sdcard connected the /dev/sda1 may not be block device you want.

Determine label or UUID by:

```
sudo blkid
```

and all entry to /etc/fstab in format:

```
UUID=85104805-cef7-41c6-9665-934e3c5ef1eb     /mount     ext3     defaults 0   0
```

or:

```
LABEL=MYPEN     /mount     ext3     defaults 0   0
```

Comment: +1 this way is better as UUID won't change and /dev/sda1 can change depending on what devices you have connected.

Comment: UUID *can* change, but it's a PITA to do and you can't do it accidentally.

Comment: @Rob: I think, to change UUID you will need to backup data, recreate filesystem and restore the data. Didn't try it.

Comment: No, there's definitely a way to do it otherwise. I found out after copying a partition with gparted.

Comment: @Rob: by copying a partition, parted recreates a similar filesystem under the cover. Anyhow, you are right, there is probably several ways to change a UUID, but fortunately it's not that easy to do it by mistake.

Answer (score 4):

If your USB drive is always connected you can put an entry in your `/etc/fstab` file if you figure out what devicename it has. To figure it out, when you have the volume mounted with Nautilus, open a Terminal and write `mount` and then check the output for the proper device. Then edit `/etc/fstab` with this, for example:

```
/dev/sda1     /mount     ext3     defaults 0   0
```